# Is there any relation between the definition of metric as defined in differential geometry and one in metric spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

If one opens a book on metric spaces, one is greeted with the definition of metric as a function of pairs of elements on a set to the real line satisfying a few properties. However, in Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry, it's given that a metric gives the relation between separations on surfaces and its mapped points in the chart.

Is there any relation between these two ideas of the same name?

Comment: Associated with a Riemannian metric on a manifold is a distance function. The distance function defines a metric space structure on the manifold.

Comment: "The relation between separations on the surfaces"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two uses of "metric", on a space $M$ while somewhat related should not be confused; while both are somehow related to lengths/distances, they have different meanings.

The "metric" in "metric space" is a  function $d:M\times M\to[0,\infty)$ satisfying 3 properties. However, the use in Riemannian geometry assumes first $M$ is a smooth manifold, and that you have a certain special $(0,2)$-tensor field $g$ on $M$; it just happens that we call this a metric tensor field. The main difference is that the metric tensor field is by its very definition an "infinitesimal description of $M$" of lengths and angles, meaning at each point $x\in M$, you have an inner product (a $(0,2)$ tensor) $g_x$ on the **tangent space** $T_xM$. On the other hand,
a distance function is by its definition a "global" property, meaning it deals directly with points of $M$.

We have the following theorem. Given a connected (hence smooth-arcwise connected) Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, we can define the function $d:M\times M\to [0,\infty)$ as
\begin{align}
d(x,y)&:=\inf_{\gamma}\,(\text{length}(\gamma)):=\inf_{\gamma}\int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))}\,dt,
\end{align}
where the infimum is taken over the set of all piecewise $C^{\infty}$ curves $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ from $x$ to $y$. The statement of the theorem is then that $d$ is a distance function on $M$ (satisfies the three axioms of a "metric space"), and that the topology $M$ inherits as a metric space using $d$ is equal to the topology $M$ already has by virtue of being a smooth manifold. Proving $d$ is a distance function isn't so hard; proving it gives the same topology is slightly harder.

There are also further interesting theorems, such as [Hopf-Rinow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem), which says (among other things) that two notions of "completeness" are equivalent: Cauchy-completeness in the sense of metric spaces is equivalent to geodesic completeness (every geodesic having the whole of $\Bbb{R}$ as the domain).

Comment: How do you mean by topology? Does the differential geometry metric define a topology?

Comment: @Buraian google the definition smooth manifold. The topology in its definition  has nothing to do with the introduction of a metric tensor